# Remove DVD drive from device manager - command line

Tags: scripting, command-line-interface, device, optical-media

Is there a way through command line to uninstall the entry under DVD/CD-ROM drives in device manager? Somehow someone applied a GPO on our top level domain and it's affected a number of things, I've resolved the other issues but when users try to access their DVD drive it says Access is Denied. Currently as a workaround if we manually go into device manager and right click and remove the DVD drive and reboot the machine it reinstalls it and then when a user tries to access it, it is fine. I'm wondering if there's a command I can push out to all machines to take care of this without having to run through that manual process on each machine.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool from Microsoft called [`devcon.exe`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) that can manipulate devices from the commandline like you're looking for. If you need the x64 version, which I assume you do since this is 2013, you [have to jump through a couple of hoops](http://www.miklos.ca/log/2010/11/devconexe-64-bit-version.html), but it's available and can do what you need it to.